# Emojicode webserver how to solve  Program panicked: Index out of bounds in 

Tags: webserver, emoji

I am writing a webserver using an emojicode language for a project, after running for a short while it crashes and returns an error statement  Program panicked: Index out of bounds in

I am using this reference as a baseline: https://www.emojicode.org/docs/packages/sockets/

The source code is below:

```
 
     8888❗ ➡ server
    ./site ➡base 
    ./site/index.html ➡ default
     
            Listen for connection and return a communication socket
             server❗ ➡ clientSocket

            Read data from Socket
             clientSocket 2048❗➡  command
            ↪command❗➡  commandstring
                    commandstring  ❗➡ fullrequest
                     fullrequest 1❗➡  file
            
                            ↪ file/
                                     default❗➡ homepage
                                     clientSocket  returnHeader ❗➕homepage❗
                            
                            ↪ file/imagesfile/css
                                     clientSocket  errorHeader❗❗
                                    
                                     

                                            ./sitefile ➡  otherpath
                                             otherpage  otherpath❗
                                                     clientSocket  returnHeader ❗➕otherpage❗
                                            
                                            ♀ error 
                                                     clientSocket  errorHeader❗❗
                                            

                                    

                            clientSocket❗
```

Error Message:

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: The questions doesn't seem clear. I would be great if you can post error screenshot. Try to paste the code because it's hard to write code from image.

Comment: @UddeshJain sorry that my question was unclear, i have written down the code and a screenshot of the error message is added.